# select column data which is datetime hour to minute into integer and put that values to a variable

Tags: informix

I have a table with one column which is of datetime hour to minute datatype.
We need to read the column data as integer and put into some collection variable which actually fits

```
CREATE function dots.shifttesting(orgid int)
returning int
DEFINE l_var LIST(datetime hour to minute not null);
SELECT pattern_start_time into l_var FROM dots.v_shift_coverage pattern_start_time where org_guid=orgid;
end function
```

5:30 has to be converted to integer while fetching data

Comment: What integer is 5:30 converted to?  I can see 530 or 330 making sense. The value 330 is the number of minutes since midnight. There won’t be gaps in that sequence.   There will be gaps if you use the 530 notation.

Comment: 5hours 30 minutes is converted to minutes which is an integer

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use the data type that you're going to need — so here, it would seem sensible to use an INTEGER instead of DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE.  However, the conversion can be done, but it is a tad contorted and very verbose:

- Convert DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE to INTERVAL MINUTE(4) TO MINUTE.
- Convert INTERVAL to CHAR.
- Convert CHAR to INTEGER.

Or, in an expression:

```
(pattern_start_time - DATETIME(00:00) HOUR TO MIMUTE)::INTERVAL MINUTE(4) TO MINUTE::CHAR(5)::INTEGER
```